# Wordpress radio button style

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button, label

Dears , i will really appreciate your support to modify the below code in WordPress , i'm trying to replace radio button with image. i tired to customize the label with CSS and it is work but i don't know how to uploaded in the WordPress,

I tried `label.avenu_addrress_house { CSS code }` in the additional CSS page, but it doesn't work.

```
<span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
<input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="house" name="avenu_addrress" id="avenu_addrress_house"><label for="avenu_addrress_house" class="radio ">
</label>
```

Comment: style="float: bottom;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border: none;
height: 75px;
width: 75px; 
background:">
<img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190705/original/pngtree-home-icon-png-image_4296701.jpg"

Comment: Try to use `label[for="avenu_addrress_house"] { CSS code }` or even `label[for=avenu_addrress_house] { CSS code }`